# Action Bar Padding

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a series of tabs with action bar sherlock. Each tab has text and an icon.

How can I change the padding around each icon, it is right next to the text in each tab. Also some tabs have large spaces (at the sides) in them and others do not. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom style for padding to your Tabs in ActionBarSherlock

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dip</item>
</style>
```